# Gradient for button not working

Tags: html, css, button, gradient

I used this site: http://www.generateit.net/gradient/index.htm?start_colour=%23FFFFFF&end_colour=%23666666&height=20&width=1&type=top to generate a 20 pixel hight and 1 pixel width gradient image.

Then I use this CSS: `background:#19558D url(images/gradient.gif) repeat-x top left;` to apply the gradient, but it doesn't seem to be working. The gradient is not being applied and the button does not look 3D. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just asking the obvious - are your images in a directory relative to where your CSS file is stored?

Comment: Umm, let's see. The "stylesheets" and "images" folders are both within the "public" folder, and the CSS file is within "stylesheets" while the image is within "images".

Comment: Do I need to change the url path in my CSS?

Comment: Yes. The image path in CSS is relative to the .css file itself. So, you'll want url(../images/gradient.gif)

Comment: thanks! the gradient works... why can't I get the background color to show now?